# Run random actions

Tags: swift2

i would anyone know how to run actions by random?

```
let action2 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.cyanColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 3)
let action3 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.purpleColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 3)
let action6 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 3)
let action7 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.yellowColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 3)
let action8 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.3, duration: 3)
let action9 = SKAction.colorizeWithColor(UIColor.orangeColor(), colorBlendFactor: 1.0, duration: 3)

let round1 = (SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([action2,action3,action6,action7,action8,action9])))
let round2 = (SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([action9,action8,action6,action7,action3,action2])))
let round3 = (SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([action3,action9,action6,action3,action2,action7])))


var colors = [round1,round2,round3]

self.scene?.runAction(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
```

I get the error on   `self.scene?.runAction(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.scene?.runAction(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))
```

This code will generate, something like:

```
 self.scene?.runAction(4)
 self.scene?.runAction(2)
```

Got the problem?

You need an array of actions, somewhere you can put the actions, and then get from it by an index.

Try

```
let arrayOfActions = [action2, action3, action4,..] //complete with the actions

 self.scene?.runAction(arrayOfActions[arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count))])
```

Comment: thanks for the help! but get the error"Type "SKAction" has no subscript members